# Maximal Area and Dimensions of a Window

Tags: calculus

came across this problem in my maths homework and I can't seem to solve it. 
Can someone maybe help me out?

A Norman window has the shape of a rectangle with a semi circle on top; diameter of the semicircle exactly matches the width of the rectangle. Find the dimensions w * h of the Norman window whose perimeter is 500in. that has maximal area.

Answer in inches:

w=

h=

There is also a picture with it.

[http://imgur.com/a/dr4ti](https://imgur.com/a/dr4ti)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you come up with a formula for the area in terms of both $w$ and $h$?  Can you come up with a formula for the perimeter in terms of both $w$ and $h$?  Using the perimeter formula and setting it equal to $500$ inches, can you now describe $h$ in terms of $w$ and constants and use this expression in the area formula?  Can you now find critical points for the area formula by using differential calculus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just calculate from what I know. Thanks to JMoravitz for the correction on $\frac{w^2}4$.

Perimeter is $$\begin{align}
500 &= 2h + w + \frac{\pi}2w\\[5pt]
&= 2h + \frac{2+\pi}2w
\end{align}$$

Since $\text{area} = wh + \dfrac12\pi\dfrac{w^2}4$,

$$h = 250 - \frac{2+\pi}4w$$

$$\text{Area} = w\left(250 - \frac{2+\pi}4w\right) + \frac12\pi\frac{w^2}4$$

Then to find the maximum:
$$\frac{\mathrm d\text{Area}}{\mathrm dw} = 250-\frac{2+\pi}2w+\pi\left(\frac w4\right) = 0$$

Solve the equation and you get the length for $w$. Solve it for length $h$ then insert it into the area formula and you get maximum area.

Comment: My bad for the parenthesis, It should've been (w^2)/4
Thx for correcting.

Comment: I think u deserve to be mentioned, or is it a regulation which must be followed?

Comment: Eh, not really a regulation, but still don't think it to be necessary.  I would prefer to read it at a glance and get the correct information without risking accidentally reading something incorrect.  If they only read the first half of the fourth line, they could run into problems.  (*of course, that's their fault more than yours at that point, but still nice to try to minimize that chance as much as possible*)

Comment: K, I found my self-proclaimed best solution in editing it.

Comment: I came up with w=140.02479
Do you guys have the same?
Now how do I rewrite the formula 
Would it just be this?

h=250-(2+pi/4)*140.02479

***Edit***
Just finished it.
w=140.02479
h=70.01239

Thanks for the help guys!